# RTEMS without /dev/console

Tags: c, termios, rtems

I'm working on an (old) application used since many years, based on RTEMS 4.6.2.
Everything well, but now I've to made some changes to test a demo: I need to use an RS232 interface to communicate with another 3rd party board. 
Unfortunately, our board has just one RS232 interface and it's currently used as debug console. I've done some researches on the web on how serial port works on RTEMS and termios, but I'm currently not able to remove the use of /dev/console.

Any idea about it?

Thanks

Comment: What are the requirements of your system? Does the list include the debug console over the serial port? If it does, then you have conflicting requirements and can't proceed until you solve that. Begin to talk to your colleagues, technical leads and architects. They might even be able to help you better and quicker than we could.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're right, but I've already done it. Problem is that bsp has been developed by a consultant years ago, and debug console has never been modified. Requirement is to change currently RS232 from debug console used by printf and fprintf to a pure raw one, that will be used to control external board. Undefining CONFIGURE_APPLICATION_NEEDS_CONSOLE_DRIVER and commenting CONSOLE_DRIVER_TABLE_ENTRY in Device_drivers do not have any effect (that leads to a bsp fail)...seems like console driver is defined somewhere else

Comment: You could "multiplex": send all RS232 to the debugger and let that pass to the other board anything that is not debugging?

Comment: Do I understand it right: You basically just want to get rid of all normal output on the console like done with printf, printk, and similar? That might is BSP dependent. Which BSP are you using? Basically there should be two possibilities: 1. You might can reopen stdout at an early stage. That won't get rid of printk and maybe lets through some boot messages. 2. Overwrite the BSPs console initialization and / or output functions. For a current RTEMS two relevant functions would be BSP_output_char and BSP_poll_char. Not sure whether 4.6 had the same names.

Comment: @ChristianMauderer you understand right. BPS is custom, developed by the "famous" consultant. It seems like if device /dev/console is not created, at first printf system crashes. I'm gonna take a look to the routines you pointed out in 2. Thanks for your advices